# r Plotly can't get xaxis tickmode="array" working for dates

Tags: r, layout, plotly, axis-labels, r-plotly

I am trying to get xaxis tickmode="array" working for dates for plotly graphs.

Here is an example:

```
x <- as.Date(c("2016-08-12", "2016-08-13", "2016-08-14", 
               "2016-08-15", "2016-08-16"))
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

str(df)

plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y) %>%
layout(xaxis = list(
  tickmode = "array",
  tickvals =
    c(as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2016-08-12", format="%Y-%m-%d"))*1000,
      as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2016-08-16", format="%Y-%m-%d"))*1000),
  type = "date"))
```

I have found various posts saying that plotly only understands dates in millisecond form (who knew?). The above code works if I substitute range= for tickvals=. I haven't found any way to affect the dates displayed using tickmode = "array". Suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

The expected result isn't clear to me, but I guess you are searching for `ticktext`.

See `schema()` for further information.

**Edit**: I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1748).

However, here is a workaround - Please check the following:

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(x = c("2016-08-12", "2016-08-13", "2016-08-14", 
                       "2016-08-15", "2016-08-16"), index = 1:5, y = 1:5)

plot_ly(df, x = ~index, y = ~y, type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(
    tickmode = "array",
    tickvals = ~index,
    ticktext = ~x))
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Sorry not be clear on what I am seeking. I would like to show only two dates, 2018-08-12 and 2018-08-16 (in my actual problem I want to show a larger number of dates that are irregularly spaced). I would prefer not to switch to a new x coordinate system (index) because this graph will be combined with others using dates on the x axis.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Using a date axis directly doesn't seem to work - That's why I posted a workaround, please see my edit above. I filed an [issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1748) on GitHub regarding this.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on this problem!